How to deploy a static sveltekit app on nginx?
trying to figure out how to host the sveltekit frontend app built with static-adapter.
Here's my svelte config:
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        // adapter-auto only supports some environments, see https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-auto for a list.
        // If your environment is not supported, or you settled on a specific environment, switch out the adapter.
        // See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapters for more information about adapters.
        adapter: adapter({
            // default options are shown
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            trailingSlash: 'always',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
          })
    }
};

export default config;

My root layout.ts:
export const prerender = true;

I then run npm run build and get .sveltekit output directory with the content below find . -maxdepth 3 -ls:
50503435        0 drwxr-xr-x    5 kilinov          staff                 160 28 May 10:53 .
50503483        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 kilinov          staff                  96 28 May 10:53 ./prerendered
50503484        0 drwxr-xr-x    4 kilinov          staff                 128 28 May 10:53 ./prerendered/pages
50503485        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                1594 28 May 10:53 ./prerendered/pages/index.html
50503486        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                1525 28 May 10:53 ./prerendered/pages/portal.html
50503436        0 drwxr-xr-x   11 kilinov          staff                 352 28 May 10:53 ./server
50503437        0 drwxr-xr-x    4 kilinov          staff                 128 28 May 10:53 ./server/entries
50503442        0 drwxr-xr-x    4 kilinov          staff                 128 28 May 10:53 ./server/entries/fallbacks
50503443        0 drwxr-xr-x    5 kilinov          staff                 160 28 May 10:53 ./server/entries/pages
50503457        0 drwxr-xr-x    6 kilinov          staff                 192 28 May 10:53 ./server/nodes
50503461        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 371 28 May 10:53 ./server/nodes/2.js
50503462        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 523 28 May 10:53 ./server/nodes/3.js
50503459        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 511 28 May 10:53 ./server/nodes/0.js
50503460        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 417 28 May 10:53 ./server/nodes/1.js
50503440        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 307 28 May 10:53 ./server/internal.js
50503487        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 864 28 May 10:53 ./server/manifest.js
50503438      184 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff               92547 28 May 10:53 ./server/index.js
50503439        0 drwxr-xr-x    6 kilinov          staff                 192 28 May 10:53 ./server/chunks
50503444       16 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                6026 28 May 10:53 ./server/chunks/internal.js
50503449        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                3347 28 May 10:53 ./server/chunks/ssr.js
50503447       16 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                5961 28 May 10:53 ./server/chunks/exports.js
50503445        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                 825 28 May 10:53 ./server/chunks/index.js
50503456        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                1220 28 May 10:53 ./server/manifest-full.js
50503441        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 kilinov          staff                  96 28 May 10:53 ./server/.vite
50503446        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                2387 28 May 10:53 ./server/.vite/manifest.json
50503458        0 drwxr-xr-x    2 kilinov          staff                  64 28 May 10:53 ./server/stylesheets
50503464        0 drwxr-xr-x    5 kilinov          staff                 160 28 May 10:53 ./client
50503465        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                1571 28 May 10:53 ./client/favicon.png
50503466        0 drwxr-xr-x    4 kilinov          staff                 128 28 May 10:53 ./client/_app
50503469        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                  27 28 May 10:53 ./client/_app/version.json
50503468        0 drwxr-xr-x    5 kilinov          staff                 160 28 May 10:53 ./client/_app/immutable
50503467        0 drwxr-xr-x    3 kilinov          staff                  96 28 May 10:53 ./client/.vite
50503470        8 -rw-r--r--    1 kilinov          staff                2642 28 May 10:53 ./client/.vite/manifest.json

But I can't see app.html (or any top-level html) anywhere - only in "prerendered" directory. I need to host this app in simple nginx server for now, I'm planning to add some backend calls later when I figure it out.
I was expecting to have a directory that would have index.html plus some JS/css/static stuff and I can then host that app in nginx like so docker run -p 80:80 -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html nginx
Thank you all in advance!

You are still using @sveltejs/adapter-auto, which as noted in a generated comment of the config, only supports certain environments. If you want to generate static pages, you have to switch the adapter to @sveltejs/adapter-static.

Thank you for this. I've ran npm install for the static adapter, but I may have forgotten to remove old comments from svelte config though. What's the best way to verify that I'm using static adapted?

Ah, I see in the import statement. Will try it out soon, hopefully this is the reason
